# mysqli image blob insert not working

Tags: php, insert, mysqli, blob

I'm trying to upload an image file to my MySql Database. I've already seacrh on the web and I finally start using the following script:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])){

$maxsize=$_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE'];       
$size=$_FILES['filename']['size'];

// getting the image info..
$imgdetails = getimagesize($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
$mime_type = $imgdetails['mime']; 

// checking for valid image type
if(($mime_type=='image/jpeg')||($mime_type=='image/gif')||($mime_type=='image/png')){
  // checking for size again
  if($size<$maxsize){
    $filename=$_FILES['filename']['name'];  
    $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']));

         if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])){
             debug('subida ok');
         }else{
             debug('fallo subida');
         }

        //echo $imgData;
        $imgDetail=addslashes($imgdetails[3]);


        $db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','user','pass', 'db');
        if($db->connect_error){
            debug('Error en la conexion : '.$db->connect_errno.
                                       '-'.$db->connect_error);
        }

        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO `image` (`name`, `image`, `type`, `size`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        if($stmt===false){ debug('Error en prepare');}
        $rc=$stmt->bind_param('sbss', $filename, $imgData, $mime_type,$imgDetail);
        if($rc===false){ debug('Error en bind');}
        if($stmt->execute()==false){ debug('error ' . $stmt->error); };
        $stmt->close();


  }else{
    debug("<font class='error'>Image to be uploaded is too large..Error uploading the image!!</font>");
  }
}else{
  debug("<font class='error'>Not a valid image file! Please upload jpeg or gif image.</font>");
}

}else{          
  switch($_FILES['filename']['error']){
case 0: //no error; possible file attack!
  debug("<font class='error'>There was a problem with your upload.</font>");
  break;
case 1: //uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini
  debug( "<font class='error'>The file you are trying to upload is too big.</font>");
  break;
case 2: //uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the html form
  debug( "<font class='error'>The file you are trying to upload is too big.</font>");
  break;
case 3: //uploaded file was only partially uploaded
  debug( "<font class='error'>The file you are trying upload was only partially uploaded.</font>");
  break;
case 4: //no file was uploaded
  debug( "<font class='error'>You must select an image for upload.</font>");
  break;
default: //a default error, just in case! 
  debug( "<font class='error'>There was a problem with your upload.</font>");
  break;
  }     
}
```

**Uploaded image seems to be find taking in care script output but looking at the database size is 0 bytes...
Does anybody knows why this?**

Comment: What's your max_allowed_packet? select @@max_allowed_packet;

Comment: max allowed packet: 1048576

Comment: Ok any other issues aside, you may not be able to upload an image larger than 1MB.  In this case, how large is your image?  Does it work with something small, like a 1k test image?

Comment: 12.7k is current size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mysqli SEND_LONG_DATA()!!!

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php

Blobs seem to be particularly frustrating for certain php/mysql (especially with the mysqli lib) server setups. This solution seems to consistently work where config settings fail to fix the problem. If its a headache to re-implement I would suggest PDO.