# PHP MySQL Insert gzcompressed into BLOB column

Tags: php, mysql, json, blob

I'm facing issues while inserting gzCompressed JSON into a MySQL BLOB Column. The size of JSON is very huge (~200MB).

Following is my Table Script:

```
CREATE TABLE `idb_mamfile_temp` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Message` blob,
  `Action` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `InternalID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`InternalID`),
  KEY `IDX_ID` (`ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `IDX_Action` (`Action`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=311802 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And my php script to add data:

```
$compressedMessage = gzcompress($jsonMessage);
$sQuery = 'INSERT into idb_mamfile_temp ("ID", "MESSAGE", "ACTION") VALUES (123,' . $compressedMessage . ', 1)';
$result = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
echo $mysqli->error . "</br>";
echo print_r($mysqli->error_list, 1);
echo "</br>" . $result;
```

This message will be read by a java code which will do the processing.
The MySQL throws the following exception:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"ID", "MESSAGE", "ACTION") VALUES (123,'x��{s�Ǚ��UP��7o�$c'��' at line 1
>
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [errno] => 1064 [sqlstate] => 42000 [error] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"ID", "MESSAGE", "ACTION") VALUES (123,'x��{s�Ǚ��UP��7o�$c'��' at line 1 ) )

I tried putting single/double quotes around the compressed Message, but still in vain. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you need to escape it; that's why.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: But as per my understanding, gzcompress produces binary data. So how to determine what all things to escape?

Comment: Prepared statements do that for you.

Comment: you have 2 solutions. 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863370/mysqli-image-blob-insert-not-working and 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052655/insert-blobs-in-mysql-databases-with-php - the latter you can easily transform to using `mysqli_`. Edit: here's a mysqli http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174824/inserting-binary-into-mysql-blob